# My pc gets hang, slowdown the performance and not responding. How to fix it?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, slowdown

My PC gets slow down n not responding everytime, I have to restart the pc every time. I have good knowledge of computer but this time I can't able to find the solution. I tried almost everything like scan disk n disk defragmenter, Antivirus scan, but no luck, infact disk defragmenter us not working properly I know there is no virus in my pc I'm using Kaspersky Internet Security 2015 I have not connected my pc to Internet since 5 months. Sometimes ago when I was studying this happened many times then I used to reinstall the entire windows 7 and the issue gone, but this time I don't want to reinstall windows, I have some important files in c drive and my documents folder like save game office work file etc, and so many softwares are installed. So please give me some tips n trick so that i can fix the issue.

My System Configuration

Windows 7 Professional (Genuine)

Core i7 3770

8GB Ram

EVGA GTX 980

ASRock Professional M Motherboard

Hard drive 2TB (1TB+1TB)

Please help.

Comment: check your HDDs for errors: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html. And next time ask this on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that can slow a machine down besides the health of HDD's or malware.  Two common factors (which can be checked by the task manager include having too many processes(background or foreground) open or having low or overutilized system resources (Processors, RAM, Cache).  I would also suggest checking the registry (search regedit) for anything suspicious looking, but make sure to create a restore point before making any changes to the registry.  I know these are basic suggestions...but oftentimes it is the simple we overlook.